# transformations divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help,

If $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, x_n> 0  $   and  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ is divergent then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$ divergent?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$, then for large enough $n$ we have $x_n\lt 1$, and therefore $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n} \gt \frac{x_n}{2}$. It follows by comparison that $\sum \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$ diverges.

If it is not the case that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$, then $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$ does not have limit $0$, and therefore $\sum \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$ diverges.

Comment: I'm sure that I have seen this before. Even so, yours is a nice solution.

Comment: @martycohen: Undoubtedly the solution is not new, and it is probably not new to MSE. As time passes, there will be fewer and fewer new solutions.

Comment: But there will always be some.